# TFS 2015 breaks variable definitions in custom XAML build files

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

I have custom code activities written before the release of TFS 2015. When we upgraded the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation` libraries from `v12.0.0.0` to `v14.0.0.0`, these code activites no longer worked. One of the errors I received is:

```
Type 'Workspace' is not defined
```

This error occurs in relation to a variable of type [`Workspace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: I had similar issues with 2013.  It took me a week of changing options and downloading libraries that Microsoft considered optional and no longer distributed with 2013.  You can download optional libraries from Microsoft which may solve your issue.  Do a search for missing items at msdn.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can run a build process that leverages custom build process activities , you must first recompile the activities with the latest .NET Framework and then check them in to the version control folder referenced by your build controller.

Also, you must use only Visual Studio 2015 to edit your build process templates.

Comment: I double checked that.  Build Controller has VS2015 installed, library accessed by controller has the correct DLLs in TFS.  When editing the XAML file in VS2015, hovering over the TF Build Activities shows them as V.14.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the reference to TFSBuildExtensions.Activities.dll resolved the issue.  Now I need to find out how to get SonarQube running in a XAML build in TFS2015.